# Solve $\int_0^\infty\frac{x^2\mathrm dx}{(x^2+a^2)(x^2+b^2)}$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

How to solve $$\int_0^\infty\frac{x^2\mathrm dx}{(x^2+a^2)(x^2+b^2)}$$
? I was trying to solve taking $x^2=\frac{1}{z}$, $x^2+a^2=z$. Even, I had taken $x=\sin\theta$. None of them were working. How can I solve it?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3625913/showing-that-int-infty-infty-fracx2x2a2x2b2dx-frac-pi?

Comment: Write it as $\cfrac{1}{a^2-b^2} \left(\cfrac{a^2}{x^2+a^2} - \cfrac{b^2}{x^2+b^2}\right)$

Comment: @MathLover My book had done same way. But, I couldn't find $x^2$ anyway

Comment: @MathLover's comment is the best method you can take, on simplifying the terms, we do get the original question only, and then $\int \dfrac{1}{x^2+a^2}dx=\dfrac{1}{a}tan^{-1}\dfrac{x}{a}$

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Showing that $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{x^2}{(x^2+a^2)(x^2+b^2)}dx=\frac{\pi}{a+b}$ via Fourier Transform](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3625913/showing-that-int-infty-infty-fracx2x2a2x2b2dx-frac-pi)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\begin{align}\int_0^{\infty}\frac{x^2}{(x^2+a^2)(x^2+b^2)}\,\mathrm dx 
&=\int_0^{\infty}\frac{1}{a^2-b^2}\left(\frac{a^2}{x^2+a^2}-\frac{b^2}{b^2+x^2}\right)\,\mathrm dx
\\&=\frac{1}{a^2-b^2}\Bigg[a\tan^{-1}(x/a)-b\tan^{-1}(x/b)\Bigg]_0^{\infty}
\\&=\frac{\pi}{2(a+b)}\end{align}$$

Comment: Perfect solution!